# OpenStreetMap(can I upload GPS coordinates to get road points?)

Tags: gps, openstreetmap

I have a problem with OpenStreetMap: actually I'm working on a project which we have different points with GPS trace of cars and we need to find points between these points, but the problem is that first I have to load them on OSM to see on the map. Does anybody know how can I do that? Because as I searched we can find Lat and Lon of places only.

Comment: Please, provide full description. What programming language? Write about plans to use it and goals.

Comment: I want to use it in Python, and the final Goal is finding the different path between points(I mean to see the trace of GPS points on the streets on map)

Comment: I have a CSV file with the number of longitudes and latitudes with timestamp collected from a vehicle. Is there a way in python (any package?) or any website where I can see the flow of longitude and latitude one after the other as per timestamp, so I can check the movement of the vehicle? I want to check the movement and analyze it.